# Calculating the dotproduct distance in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, dot-product

What I need to do is, calculate dot product distance between the ratings of two customers. The ratings of the customers are recorded in a hashmap.

```
private HashMap<String,int[]> ratingmap;
```

The key in the hashmap is the customer name, and associated with it are ratings of that customer(his ratings of the books)

How will I do this?

```
/**
 * calculate dot product distance between the ratings of two customers
 * @param name1 String name of customer 
 * @param name2 String name of customer 
 * @return int distance or ILLEGAL_INPUT if name1 or name2 are not customers
 */
public int distance(String name1, String name2) 
{
    return 0; //replace with code
}
```

And here is the other bit of detail given at the `RatingsAnalysis` class

```
//collection of rated book titles
private BookList books;
//collection of customers and their ratings
private RatingsMap ratings;
//use a list of customer names from the ratings map for looping through the map
private ArrayList<String> customernames;
```

Comment: Please define the "dot product distance" in this context.

Comment: the dot product distance is how 'closely' related the ratings for both the customers are. Like each customer is allowed to make ratings on a book, from what i can see is that its asking how close the ratings are i.e the difference

Comment: But it's not clear what calculation that would involve in this context.  Please edit your question to give an example of what calculation you want to perform.

Comment: Would it not be just to subtract all the int for each customer(only cust1 and cust2 in this case)

Comment: Seems to me you want to build two vectors (one for each user) where each dimension is a rating for the same given book? Then calculate the dot product of these vectors . . . Would you fill in a '0' if no rating is given or remove this dimension from the vectors, bc. '0' could be the same as a very negative rating? Does that make sense to you?

Comment: @Danial: There is no subtraction involved in a standard dot product.  Also, what happens if cust1 and cust2 haven't rated identical items?

Comment: Yes! thats what i want. Thankyou

Comment: if no rating is given you would fill in zero, i would think

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the member field

```
private RatingsMap ratings;
```

in `RatingsAnalysis` is the `Map` of names => ratings.  Your task in the `distance` method is this:

1. Look up the rating for `name1` and `name2` and store them in local variables (**hint**: use the `get` method defined on the `Map` interface)
2. Perform the dot product analysis on these two ratings you obtained above.  You either know how to do this or need to provide more information on its meaning with respect to a `Rating` in this question.
3. Return the result

As a side note, the RatingsMap can and should be more strongly typed:

```
private RatingsMap<String, Rating> ratings;
```

EDIT : Adding skeleton code requested...

```
public int distance(String name1, String name2) 
{
    Rating r1 = this.ratings.get(name1);
    Rating r2 = this.ratings.get(name2);

    if(r1 != null && r2 != null) { 
       return ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes sounds logical, can i get a walking skeleton code on how to perform this, cause at the moment i cant seem to figure it out

Comment: The 'Rating'word doesnt work from Rating r1, and Rating r2 , what would I replace with the word "Rating" ?Im sorry im really useless at this

Comment: What classes were given to you as part of this assignment?  Rating is a class

Comment: public RatingsAnalysis()
    {
        books = new BookList();
        ratings = new RatingsMap();
        customernames = ratings.getCustomerNames();
    }

Comment: the classes were RatingsAnalysis, RatingsMap, Booklist

Comment: Yes i put in RatingsMap for it and it works. now it says cannot find symbol method get(java.lang.string)